# Avoid systemd unit (service) to be logged in journal

Tags: server, systemd, systemd-journald

To produce metrics on some disks I have setup a [systemd.timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) + [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

That timer spins up every 10 seconds, and I would like to avoid my journal be spammed every time this small script get spawned and then succedes.

Journal writes multiple lines like that

```
Jan 04 17:21:31 hostname systemd[1]: personal.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit personal.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

Moreover there is an *audit* on every service start

```
Jan 04 17:22:31 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=personal comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 04 17:22:31 hostname kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1578158551.035:11612): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=personal comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good article about this was written by Daniel Aleksandersen

[Adjust or silence a systemd service’s logging levels](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/systemd-log-levels.html)

Override service unit:

```
systemctl edit Your.service
```

Add a LogLevelMax parameter.

```
[Service]
LogLevelMax=2
```

The standard log levels are emergency (0), alert (1), critical (2), error (3), warning (4), notice (5), info (6), and debug (6). 
Restart the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart Your.service
```

**Silence standard output**

Create a service unit override:

```
systemctl edit Your.service
```

Direct the output to null.

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
#StandardError=null
```

restart the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart Your.service
```

The service will no longer forward standard output messages to the journal.

For more details on this visit Daniel's blog at the link above and buy him a coffee

Comment: Thanks for the link to that blog post. It helped me fix a related issue by following the "Silencing a desktop app" section of it.